# How do I restart my X server?

Tags: xorg, ubuntu-gnome

I turned off my X server with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. I used <kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to reboot and now I can't get the X server back on.

The motherboard posts and I get the same screen as I had when I used the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> command except now none of the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> commands work. How can I get the X server running again?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>restarts the computer from the black screen I'm getting frozen on. Also, magic <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key makes a higher pitch post noise. Thats the only response I can get at this screen.